# How to merge multiple documents in MongoDB and convert fields' values into fields

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that I have managed to process using an `aggregation` pipeline to produce the following result:

```
[ 
  { 
    _id: 'Complex Numbers', 
    count: 2 
  }, 
  { _id: 'Calculus', 
    count: 1 
  }
]
```

But the result that I am aiming for is something like the following:

```
{
  'Complex Numbers': 2,
  'Calculus': 1
}
```

is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- to convert to `{}` we need somethings like `[[k1 v1] ...]` OR `[{"k" "..." :v "..."}]`
- first stage

  - converts each document to `[{"k" ".." , "v" ".."}]`
  - then `arrayToObject`
  - and replace root
- so we have each document like `"Complex Numbers": 2`
- the group is used to combine all those documents in 1 document
- and then replace the root with that one document

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70203012)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$replaceRoot": 
    {"newRoot": {"$arrayToObject": [[{"k": "$_id", "v": "$count"}]]}}},
  {"$group": {"_id": null, "data": {"$mergeObjects": "$$ROOT"}}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$data"}}])
```